# ssis package is not being execute with job scheduled on Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I have developed an SSIS package and deployed it on the SQL Server which uploads flat files in the database. I scheduled it to be run every 30 seconds. the job is being executed successfully but my SSIS package is not being executed. I mean I am not getting any result.

but while I am executing the package by right-clicking on the deployed package it gives me result.

Note - Scheduled job history doesn't show any error. it shows the success message of execution.

Comment: There's very little detail we actually have here to work on. I would suggest consulting the execution log in SSISDB for the package; perhaps that will tell you more. Unfortunately we have nothing else to go on other than "it's not working as expected, there is no error", making any answer we could give pure guesswork and stabs in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by giving folder permission to the user from which the package was being executed.